# Virtual hosts on apache

Tags: apache, magento, virtualhost

I have this configuration in httpd.conf file.

```
#NameVirtualHost <ip_address>

<VirtualHost <ip_address>:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/<domain_folder>
    ServerName <doman>
    ErrorLog logs/<doman>-error_log
    CustomLog logs/<doman>-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

after the this configuration if i type "http://domain.com" its displayed home page
with out any issue but when i click contacts page "http://domain.com/contacts/"
its displayed 404 error.

is this  configuration error ? 
Note : this is aptana marketplace (magento) app

If I type "domain.com/index.php/contacts/"; its working fine.

Comment: if i type "http://domain.com/index.php/contacts/"  its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `.htaccess` on your magento host. In apache default config you can add this:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: changed the apache configuration file but still issue is there. please can you advise me ?

Comment: did you restarted apache after changes made? `sudo service apache2 restart`. Also have a look into `.htaccess` file. Try to replace `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` line with `RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
`

Comment: Yes i restated the server

Comment: Try to write somesing bad in your .htaccess file like `asdsadasda` in the beginning. Will the "http://domain.com" load or will crash with the `Internal Server Error` error?

Comment: still same issue , i think issue in apache configuration end but could find the extract issue, if you any idea please let me know .

Comment: If you don't have an `Internal Server Error` after messing with **.htaccess** file and still see **404** error then you still have not enabled usage of .htaccess files with the config mentioned above. Make sure you have added the code from the answer to the **default.conf** apache site in **/etc/apache2/sites-available** and this file symlinked or copied to **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled**